# Epson xp205 printer status "stopped"

Tags: printing, epson

Ubuntu 16.04 beta2  printer Epson xp205.  After a bit of working around I got the Epson driver installed.  All looks good except that the printer status is "stopped"  Tried releasing job but still at stopped.

Jobs show in print queue and the printer is enabled.

I did a clean install of 16.04 due to the problems I was having with Ubuntu 15.10, but I have many of the same problems in 16.04 plus a few more.

What should I do?

Comment: try this:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/794466/cups-print-jobs-on-ubuntu-server-16-04-received-and-successful-but-no-actual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deleting all the print jobs in the queue and turning the printer off for 30 seconds.

Under the printers properties check that 'Enabled' is ticked and the error policy is set to 'Retry job'.

If these don't work paste the output from `lpinfo -v` into your question and attach /var/log/cups/error_log.

Comment: Hi Steve Sorry for the delay. tried deleting queue and switching printer off/on. Yes it is enables and set to retry

Comment: sorry hit the wrong button.   margaret@HPwin7:~$ lpinfo -v
network ipps
network beh
network https
network http
network lpd
network ipp14
network ipp
network socket
direct hp
direct hpfax
network dnssd://EPSON%20XP-205%20207%20Series._ipp._tcp.local/?uuid=cfe92100-67c4-11d4-a45f-a4ee57de7897
network lpd://192.168.0.3:515/PASSTHRU
margaret@HPwin7:~$ sudo /var/log/cups/error_log.
[sudo] password for margaret: 
sudo: /var/log/cups/error_log.: command not found
margaret@HPwin7:~$ 
Thanks

Comment: var/log/cups/error_log (no dot) is a file. Paste its contents into your question using a text editor like gedit.

Comment: sorry I know how to open gedit but not how to use it to direct it to the directory. Also software updater said :Sorry to be such a thicko.   Could this be the problem please.  Why 1386/packages as opposed to 86-64    for 64bit pc

Comment: I would do a clean install of 14.04 LTS as 16.04 has only just been released.To paste contents of a file into a question open it with gedit, select the content with the mouse, right click and choose copy. Then click on the word edit under your question left click the position you want to paste into then right click and choose paste. If it has too many characters paste into paste.ubuntu.com and add the link into the question.

Comment: Thanks so much - Ubuntu 18.04; turns out "'Enabled' is ticked" was my problem. Cheers!