# CUPS print jobs on Ubuntu Server 16.04 received and "successful", but no actual printing

Tags: server, printing, hp

I'm working on setting up a local server, part of which is going to be a CUPS print server using a HP LaserJet 1018.

I was able to get CUPS set up and running, and I'm able to install the printer just fine.

However, when I go to print a job, it's received and appears to be successful, but nothing ever actually gets printed.

Here's the contents of `/var/log/cups/error_log`:

```
$ cat /var/log/cups/error_log 
E [03/Jul/2016:17:36:24 -0400] [cups-deviced] PID 11834 (gutenprint52+usb) stopped with status 1!
W [03/Jul/2016:17:42:23 -0400] CreateProfile failed: org.freedesktop.ColorManager.AlreadyExists:profile id \'HP_LaserJet_1018-Gray..\' already exists
W [03/Jul/2016:17:53:05 -0400] Notifier for subscription 2 (dbus://) went away, retrying!
E [03/Jul/2016:17:54:25 -0400] [cups-deviced] PID 21003 (gutenprint52+usb) stopped with status 1!
E [03/Jul/2016:17:54:32 -0400] [cups-deviced] PID 21031 (gutenprint52+usb) stopped with status 1!
W [03/Jul/2016:17:54:48 -0400] CreateProfile failed: org.freedesktop.ColorManager.AlreadyExists:profile id \'HP_LaserJet_1018-Gray..\' already exists
W [03/Jul/2016:17:54:54 -0400] CreateProfile failed: org.freedesktop.ColorManager.AlreadyExists:profile id \'HP_LaserJet_1018-Gray..\' already exists
E [03/Jul/2016:18:02:17 -0400] [cups-deviced] PID 21389 (gutenprint52+usb) stopped with status 1!
W [03/Jul/2016:18:02:36 -0400] CreateProfile failed: org.freedesktop.ColorManager.AlreadyExists:profile id \'HP_LaserJet_1018-Gray..\' already exists
W [03/Jul/2016:18:02:46 -0400] CreateProfile failed: org.freedesktop.ColorManager.AlreadyExists:profile id \'HP_LaserJet_1018-Gray..\' already exists
```

and some of `/var/log/cups/access_log`:

```
localhost - - [03/Jul/2016:18:02:36 -0400] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 401 353 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - cactus [03/Jul/2016:18:02:36 -0400] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 353 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
192.168.0.106 - cactus [03/Jul/2016:18:02:36 -0400] "POST /admin HTTP/1.1" 200 14525 - -
192.168.0.106 - cactus [03/Jul/2016:18:02:46 -0400] "POST /admin HTTP/1.1" 200 409 - -
localhost - - [03/Jul/2016:18:02:46 -0400] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 401 24541 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - cactus [03/Jul/2016:18:02:46 -0400] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 24541 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
192.168.0.106 - cactus [03/Jul/2016:18:02:46 -0400] "POST /admin HTTP/1.1" 200 2425 - -
localhost - - [03/Jul/2016:18:03:00 -0400] "POST /printers/HP_LaserJet_1018 HTTP/1.1" 200 423 Print-Job successful-ok
192.168.0.106 - - [03/Jul/2016:18:03:41 -0400] "POST /printers/HP_LaserJet_1018 HTTP/1.1" 200 394 Validate-Job successful-ok
192.168.0.106 - - [03/Jul/2016:18:03:41 -0400] "POST /printers/HP_LaserJet_1018 HTTP/1.1" 200 343 Create-Job successful-ok
192.168.0.106 - - [03/Jul/2016:18:03:41 -0400] "POST /printers/HP_LaserJet_1018 HTTP/1.1" 200 440 Send-Document successful-ok
192.168.0.106 - - [03/Jul/2016:18:08:57 -0400] "POST /printers/HP_LaserJet_1018 HTTP/1.1" 200 469 Validate-Job successful-ok
192.168.0.106 - - [03/Jul/2016:18:08:57 -0400] "POST /printers/HP_LaserJet_1018 HTTP/1.1" 200 434 Create-Job successful-ok
192.168.0.106 - - [03/Jul/2016:18:08:57 -0400] "POST /printers/HP_LaserJet_1018 HTTP/1.1" 200 80371 Send-Document successful-ok
localhost - - [03/Jul/2016:18:09:03 -0400] "POST /printers/HP_LaserJet_1018 HTTP/1.1" 200 227 Create-Job successful-ok
localhost - - [03/Jul/2016:18:09:03 -0400] "POST /printers/HP_LaserJet_1018 HTTP/1.1" 200 281 Send-Document successful-ok
localhost - - [03/Jul/2016:18:09:16 -0400] "POST /printers/HP_LaserJet_1018 HTTP/1.1" 200 423 Print-Job successful-ok
```

and a screenshot of the jobs CUPS page:

[image]

How can I get the server to actually print the pages?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with HP LaserJet 1020. Removing **printer-driver-gutenprint** package solved the problem for me; it seems the current version is broken. You may also need to uninstall cups, clear /etc/cups/ directory and install cups again.

Comment: My problem was the the printer said not connected even though it was online and on the network.  I used synaptic to uninstall the printer-driver-gutenprint package, and reinstalled the printer queue.  After that, it printed fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue - the job was successfully added, the printer (Brother MFC-J*) lighted up and showed that it is printing on its display - but then it simply finished without printing anything.

The same symptoms occurred with CUPS.
After adding the printer with model "everywhere" (IPP Everywhere) the page printed! So the ipptool must be used with an IPP Everywhere adjusted job.